# Set Jenkins Windows Slave Screen Resolution For Selenium Tests

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, screen-resolution

I got a Jenkins windows 7 slave for testing my UI webapp using Selenium WebDriver (*java, with Firefox and chrome drivers; machine is vmware vm*).
Also, slave is connected to jenkins master using JNLP agent.

**Problem is**: Tests fail on slave, since resolution seems to be 800x600 whereas I need 1920x1080-ish.

Setting selenium web driver windows size won't do it, i.e.

```
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Any ideas? I'm trying to figure out where display resolution configuration should be done. Should it be done on JVM side (as test is execute by jenkins slave)? Or is it a windows issue?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and we resolved it by setting up the Jenkins slave on windows an **admin** session of RDP started from a PC with a 1920x1080 resolution screen.
Start -> run -> `mstsc /admin`

This opens the Jenkins slave in the desired resolution.
Then, you just disconnect the RDP session and this leaves the session running in the desired resolution.

I hope this helps.

Comment: can you elaborate? Did you just login via RDP manually? was it a one time thing, or you do it automatically before every build?

Comment: The login was manually done once. This creates the logged in session which then I run the Jenkins slave in. After that, I disconnect and leave the session running for Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The display setup should be a one time activity performed on slave. You will have to remote into slave as admin using RDP to set resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, then I used Phantom JS driver instead of Chrome

try this:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1936, 1176));
```

Problem resolved from my end

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me is to run Chrome in a 'headless' mode (without GUI). It works with Jenkins Agent running as a service, when GUI is not available.
Here is the code sample of the web driver initialization (C#, I guess will be similar in java):

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
options.AddArgument("Headless");
options.AddArgument("window-size=1920,1080");

driver = new ChromeDriver(@"<path>\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.2.37.0\driver\win32", options);
```